# Error message: “Output argument (and maybe others) not assigned during function call”

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this function which accepts row/col coordinates of an image and returns the directions at which neighbouring pixels change.

```
function [d] = p_directions(row, col, img)

if img(row, col+1) == 2
  if img(row, col) == 3
    d = 'A+'; 
  elseif img(row, col) == 1
    d = 'B+';    
  elseif img(row, col) == 2
    d = NaN;
  end
end

if img(row, col) == 2
   if img(row, col+1) == 3
    d = 'A-';
   elseif img(row, col+1) == 1
    d = 'B-';
   end
end
end
```

function call:

`[row, col] = find_row_col(A);
 [d]    = p_directions(row, col, img)`

Error message:

`Error in p_directions (line 15)
if img(row, col + 1) == 2`

`Output argument "d" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "p_directions".`

I would want to believe the error is coming from the first line of my script (‘line 15’) in which case the variable ‘d’ is not even computed. I am new to programming and I have no idea what on earth could be wrong with the first line of my function script? Please any help, suggestions or advice on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function `p_directions` will only assign a value to `d` if any of your nested if conditions is true. You have not assigned a "default" value to return if none of them is true.

Your two blocks of conditions start with `if img(row, col+1) == 2` and `if img(row, col) == 2` respectively. What if none of them is true, since both `img(row,col)` and `img(row,col+1)` are not 2? Then `d` will not have a value and Matlab doesn't know what to return. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is one case where the error says it all...

You need to specify a default value for `d`. Typically you would choose a value so that when it is returned you know something went wrong. So directly after the function call, you might consider putting something like

```
d = -1
```

or you can add else statements...

```
if  
   ...
else 
   d = -1
```

The problem is that you will only ever get into your `if` statements if the `img` value is 2 at either of the points you specify. If it doesn't then the return value never gets assigned.

Comment: Many thanks to all. I have fixed this now with the help of a friend. The problem was actually with the loop within which the function is called. As for your comments you are absolutely correct as this also would have been the case even if the loop were to be right. I guess i just learnt a lot out of this error.